# Broken arrows in Tikz - Two lines block diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to make a two lines block diagram, and connecting the two lines is quiet difficult for me since I am a beginner in Tikz, here is my code, the best I could do :
[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{schemabloc} 
    \usetikzlibrary{circuits}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[cross/.style={path picture={ 
                \draw[black]
                (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west) (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);
            }}]
            \sbEntree{E}
            \sbBloc[8]{fir1}{$FIR_1$}{E}
            \sbRelier[ADC Output]{E}{fir1}
            \sbBlocL{dec1}{$\downarrow 2$}{fir1}    
            \sbBlocL{fir2}{$FIR_2$}{dec1}
            \sbBlocL{dec2}{$\downarrow 2$}{fir2}    

            \node[draw,circle,cross,minimum width=1 cm, right of=dec2, node distance = 5em ](mixer){};
            \sbRelier{dec2}{mixer}
            \node[above of=mixer, node distance = 5em](fi){$Sin(2\pi f_It)$};

            %   \sbBloc[12]{fir3}{$FIR_3$}{E}
            \node [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, below of=fir1, node distance = 5em ](fir3){$FIR_3$};
            \node [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, right of=fir3, node distance = 5em ](dec3){$\downarrow R_3$};
            \node [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, right of=dec3, node distance = 7em ](resa){Resampling};  
            \sbRelier{fir3}{dec3}       
            \sbRelier{dec3}{resa}

            \draw[->] (fi) -- (mixer);
            \node [ right of=mixer](a){};
            \node [ below of=a](b){};
            \node [ below of=E](c){};
            \node [ below of=c, node distance=-6pt](d){};
            \draw[->] (mixer) |- (d) ;
            \draw[->] (d) |- (fir3);
            %   \draw[-] (c) -- (d);
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you question is a bit unclear. Is the long arrow your problem?  Instead of the last two `\draw` lines, try `\draw[->] (mixer) |- (d.center)  |- (fir3);`. Explanation: `(d)` is an empty node, even empty ones have a minimal size and lines to and from will hit this boundary. But we only want to use it as stepping stone, so we explicitly use the center and go through it instead.

Comment: Nodes with empty content should be coordinates....

Comment: @PaulGaborit does `\coordinate` work with the `below of=` syntax?

Comment: @daleif Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Since you receive answers in above comments, this answer is more focused to off.topis issue: how to simply MWE, use up-to-date syntax, and corect names for math operators. For changes made, I use two TikZ libraries: `calc` and `positioning`. Of course in MWE below is used (only one) coordinate instead of empty nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                positioning}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
    \newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3em and 2em,
mixer/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=3em,
    path picture={\draw[black]  (\ppbb.south east) -- (\ppbb.north west)
                                (\ppbb.south west) -- (\ppbb.north east);},
    node contents={}
              },
block/.style = {draw, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em}
              ]
\sbEntree{E}
\sbBloc[8]{fir1}{$FIR_1$}{E}
\sbRelier[ADC Output]{E}{fir1}
\sbBlocL{dec1}{$\downarrow 2$}{fir1}
\sbBlocL{fir2}{$FIR_2$}{dec1}
\sbBlocL{dec2}{$\downarrow 2$}{fir2}

\node (mixer)   [mixer,right=of dec2];
\sbRelier{dec2}{mixer}
\node (fi)      [above=of mixer] {$\sin(2\pi f_It)$};

%   \sbBloc[12]{fir3}{$FIR_3$}{E}
\node (fir3) [block, below=of fir1] {$FIR_3$};
\node (dec3) [block, right=of fir3] {$\downarrow R_3$};
\node (resa) [block, right=of dec3] {Resampling};
\sbRelier{fir3}{dec3}
\sbRelier{dec3}{resa}
%
\coordinate[left=of $(fir1.west)!0.5!(fir3.west)$] (a);

\draw[->] (fi) -- (mixer);
\draw[->] (mixer) |- (a)  |- (fir3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]